# Error (no se encontraron el identificador y no están definidos) al calcular el código de control de un ISBN

Tags: c++

He realizado este programa, que me calcula el código de control de un ISBN
pero tengo un error en lo que es:

**gets** -> `gets(isbn);`

Y en:

**isdigit** -> `if (!isdigit(isbn[i])) {`

Según visual studio dice que no encontraron el identificador y no están definidos, lo cual se me hace algo raro pero no estoy seguro que es lo que realice mal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char isbn[100];
    int largo, control, total = 0, i, error = 0;

    printf("Introduce el codigo: ");
    gets(isbn);
    largo = strlen(isbn);

    if (largo == 10) {
        for (i = 0; i < largo; i++) {
            if (!isdigit(isbn[i])) {
                error = 1;
            }
        }
        if (error == 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < largo - 1; i++) {
                total += (i + 1) * (isbn[i] - '0');
            }
            control = total % 11;
            if (control != (isbn[9] - '0')) {
                error = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        error = 1;
    }
    switch (error) {
    case 0:
        printf("Formato correcto.");
        break;

    case 1:
        printf("Formato incorrecto.");
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("El digito de control no es valido.");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tienes que añadir `#include <ctype.h>` para tener `isdigit`. Sobre el porque
`gests` te dira error, tengo que preguntar: Que compilador usas? Y que estandar
de C estas usando para trabajar? `gets` se removio en `C11`. Y si estas usando
un compilador de C++, se removio en `C++14`.

Comment: La verdad no tengo idea cual uso, pero me descargue el compilador de microsoft visual c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pero no estoy seguro que es lo que realice mal.

Lo primero que estás haciendo mal es usar `char*` en vez de `std::string`. Ya que estás programando en C++ lo suyo sería hacer uso de las utilidades de C++ en vez de las heredadas de C.

Ahora bien, el error no se produce por esto sino porque no has añadido los includes que contienen la declaración de las funciones que estás usando:

```
#include <cctype> // Para isdigit
```

El caso de `gets` es diferente. Esta función es insegura, ya que no conoce el tamaño del buffer y puede hacer que el mismo se desborde.

Esta función se marcó como *deprecada* en C++11 y se eliminó de forma definitiva en C++14.

Lo dicho, si en vez de usar `char*` usases `std::string` esto no te habría pasado

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Introduce el codigo: ";
    std::string isbn;
    std::cin >> isbn;

    // ...
}
```